Help to configure an LTspice PLL simulation
I never tried PLLs before and to gain some insight I'm trying to simulate CD4046Bg in LTspice where I want the output to phase-lock and follow the input signal. I tried so far the below:

But I get an output with much higher freq. as follows:

I might be doing something fundamentally wrong but couldn't figure it out myself.
(I want to use this as a PLL where output syncs with the input signal)

You're probably too far out of lock range; PLLs have a limited range of frequencies they can lock to. In the case of the CD4046, this range is programmed by your choice of resistors and capacitors.

With the chosen components (10k, 10nF) the center frequency of the VCO is about 5kHz while the reference frequency is only 50Hz.

I changed the input to 5kHz now I get zero output.

I don't know this chip, but you likely have to simulate for 100's or 1000's of cycles of the reference clock to get locked in. This might take a LOOOONG time. Just one and a fraction of a cycle is absolutely not enough to get locked. You might speed it up by setting an initial condition on C1 that is closer to the locked condition.

You probably also want the RC time of R1C1 to be substantially longer than the reference clock period, to hold up the VCO control voltage between edges of the reference (when there's no new information available to adjust the VCO from)

Where did you get the SPICE model from?

it was already in LTspice installed

@pnatk - Zero output from the VCO? The VCO should output a signal even if unlocked and with the wrong frequency. Open the loop, apply a variable 0...5V voltage to the VCO and take a look at the the voltage/frequency range of the output signal. With the loop closed, monitor the tuning voltage, this should tell you a lot about what is going on. The PLL filter is also far from being OK.

Im also having issues to understand why the VCO locks at around Vcc/2:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/720042/in-a-type-1-pll-will-the-output-and-input-have-phase-difference-after-phase-is-l So far still dont get it

You are mistaken.  LTspice does not ship with a CD4046 SPICE model.  You or someone else must have installed it previously.  Regardless, I think I located where it was acquired from: https://www.electro-tech-online.com/threads/new-spice-model-for-cd4046b-phase-locked-loop-ic.149093/

As I don't have a model for the 4046 I substituted it with an equivalent, simple (3rd order) PLL circuit. The VCO range is 2...8kHz with a convenient center frequency of 5kHz. The reference frequency is 5kHz. As I chose a rather small PLL bandwidth (~100Hz), the VCO takes quite some time to lock at turn on. VCO and reference are 90° apart.
If you adjust the VCO in the CD4046 to the same frequency range you can use the PLL filter shown. Monitor the tuning voltage, reference and VCO frequency in LTspice.


