In a type 1 PLL will the output and input have phase difference after phase is locked?
Regarding XOR based type 1 digital PLL, I can see that after the phase-locking the output freq. and the input freq. will be same.
But how about the phase? Will the phase difference be zero or? I cannot find any info about it.

edit:
XOR LP VCO


Edit 2:
Can someone modify the above circuit so that phase locking occurs when the vco_in is Vdd/4? Only then I will be convinced.

The XOR phase detector locks at Pi/2 phase difference when the average output voltage is zero respectively Vdd/2 for a single supply, digital type XOR gate.

When using an XOR, the "neutral" phase difference will be 90°. I mean, if you think about it a little it makes sense; when the two signals are at 90°, the average output voltage will be half Vcc thus, putting it right in the middle of the VCO input control range.

"...when the two signals are at 90°, the average output voltage will be half Vcc" I completely get that part. But my confusion is more fundamental here. Why does the locking occur at exactly half the voltage(Vcc/2)? Its a mystery for me. What's so special bout that voltage? What decides the mechanism to be locked at that votage? Spent hours but didnt get it.

You want locking to occur in the mid range of the VCO input to give maximum possibility for dealing with frequency deviations up and down. Of course, it doesn't have to and you could decide that 25% of Vcc is where you want locking to occur. 25% would be equivalent to a significantly different phase angle. It's the designer's call @pnatk

so do you mean that the VCO forces the "VCO input" to settle at Vcc/2?

The "special thing" about Vcc/2 is that it is the voltage furthest away from both Vcc and 0V, meaning you get the most room for adjustment both in the positive and the negative direction.

My confusion is about what sets the ref value as Vcc/2. Is there an opmap sonewhere with a fixed Vcc/2 ? is it hidden in the vco like this https://i.sstatic.net/EOiPHQZP.jpg? something must be setting it to vcc/2

Your image is flawed. If your VCO produces 1 MHz at Vcc/2, it might produce 2 MHz with the input at Vcc and, it might produce 500 kHz with the input at 0 volt. So, if the XOR phase detector naturally produces Vcc/2 when the phase difference at its inputs is 90 degree then it will make the VCO output equal to 1 MHz. If you then closed the loop to "create" a PLL and, your XOR reference input is only 750 kHz then, the system will settle down with 750 kHz on the VCO output and around Vcc/4 average DC level coming from the XOR.

@Andyaka Please see my edit. I made the XOR LP and VCO as separate models https://i.sstatic.net/MdvNkHpB.png and get results where locking happens around 2.5V = Vcc/2  https://i.sstatic.net/0foIuYCY.png But I still do not get what sets it to around Vcc/2. Why does it exactly lock at that voltage. Is there some opmap inside hidden that force VCO to settle at Vcc/2? (sorry for digging Im about to give up trying to understand it after watching  10 videos  and spending days )

If the VCO produces a frequency that is exactly equal to your reference frequency when the VCO input is 2.5 volts then, that is what will happen. If you lowered the reference frequency by 10% you will see a slightly different control voltage at the input to your VCO. By how much it changes from 2.5 volts depends on the VCO conversion gain (MHz per volt) @pnatk

@pnatk if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Im not done at all. I still dont get where is that 90 degree come from. I spent huge time and still couldnt find a mathematical didactic proof. Can that 90 degree be about integration due to LP filter?

No, the 90 degrees comes from how an EXOR works. When the input and the reference are 90 degrees apart the EXOR produces an average output voltage that is Vcc/2. It's no more complicated than that.

There will, in general, be a phase difference since the phase detector needs to produce a control voltage that will drive the VCO to the same frequency as the input. The difference will be between 0 and 180°, with a 90° difference producing Vcc/2. From the CD4046 datasheet:

So, for example, if your VCO requires Vcc/4 input to produce the same frequency as the input, then the phase difference when locked will be about 45°.
Here is a very simple simulation of a PLL locking in using the type I ex-or phase comparator:

As you can see, when it stabilizes there is a constant phase difference between input and output and the VCO input is not Vdd/2:

You can easily download the LTspice program and run these simulations yourself to get a feel for the behavior. You can also feed constant or swept voltages to the VCO input and ignore the rest of the chip (just look at the VCO behavior).

I dont understand. Why does the locking occur at exactly half the voltage(Vcc/2)? Its a mystery for me. What's so special bout that voltage? What decides the mechanism to be locked at that voltage?

It does not unless your VCO happens to provide exactly the input frequency at Vcc/2. Naturally that would tend to be the design goal, but there will be a difference in general.

so do you mean that the VCO forces the "VCO input" to settle at Vcc/2? –

The nature of the VCO determines what voltage it needs to get to the lock frequency. If that happens to be Vcc/2 then it will settle there when locked.

it means i wll never understand what is going on unless i know the internal workings of vco :((

All you need to know is how many volts in = how many Hz out

Can we say that VCC/2 would typically be the reference voltage at the input of the op amp which is inside he VCO? Maybe that confuses me because in the type1 diagram its not shown

I will make drawing and come back

I tried to draw here https://i.sstatic.net/EOiPHQZP.jpg , is that whats happening?

of course i for got to add the voltage to freq converter at the vco output.

More or less. There's a certain slope of Hz/volt, like a gain.

Please see my edit. I made the XOR LP and VCO as separate models https://i.sstatic.net/MdvNkHpB.png and get similar results https://i.sstatic.net/0foIuYCY.png But I still do not get what sets it to around Vcc/2. Why does it exactly lock at that voltage.
